# Cannot use registerReceiver in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I cannot use registerReceiver in BroadcastReceiver. I read that I cannot do that then how should I confirm that my SMS has been sent?

BroadCastReceiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String SENT="sent";
    String DELIVERED="delivered";
    public final String tag="com.example.pritesh.smstimer";
    public MyReceiver() {

    }

    //@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i(tag,"Sending");
            final NotificationManager notificationManager=  (NotificationManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent intent1=new Intent(context,Time_Picker.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent1,0);
        //Notification for sent msg
        final Notification.Builder notification_sent=new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("SMS SENT")
                    .setContentText("Your SMS has Been Sent")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.favicon);
        //Notification for msg not sent
        final Notification.Builder notification_notsent=new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("SMS SENT")
                .setContentText("Your SMS was not sent due to no network service")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.favicon);
        //Intent for sending confirmation

        Intent sent=new Intent(SENT);
        //PendingIntent for sending confirmation

        PendingIntent sentIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,sent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //Receiver for sent confirmation

        Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED);

        PendingIntent deliverPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, deliveryIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String result = "";

                switch (getResultCode()) {

                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        result = "Transmission successful";
                        notificationManager.notify(0,notification_sent.build());
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        result = "No service";
                        notificationManager.notify(0,notification_notsent.build());
                        break;
                }
            }
        },new IntentFilter(SENT));

        context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Deliverd",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));


            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(Time_Picker.Phone,null, Time_Picker.Message, sentIntent
                    ,deliverPI);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Sms Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

How should I send the sentIntent   to confirm whether sms sent or not

Manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pritesh.smstimer" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/favicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Time_Picker"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity="" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".NotificationReciever"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot register dynamic `BroadcastReceiver`s inside of another `BroadcastReceiver`. This is because the system enforces that a `BroadcastReceiver` finishes it's work within a short period of time (I think it's either 5 or 10 seconds).

You can create another `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered in your AndroidManifest. The `<intent-filter>` should include `<action>` elements that match the custom action strings you use in your code.